# Is it bad design to require my website to have a cron script running every minute or two?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

Basically I'm designing an alert system in PHP with CodeIgniter. I want the alerts to be "scheduled" by inserting a database row and then sent out in batches periodically. The alerts are sent out via email.

The only way I can think to achieve this is to require a cron script to call a CLI-only controller every minute or so that checks for scheduled alerts and sends them if it finds anything.

Something is telling me that having a cron script run so often is poorly designed but I can't think of any other way to do it.

Advice?

Comment: Why not just send the email outright? instead of inserting a row to be sent later, just send it!

Comment: Question -> can't you put the schedule once every hour? minutely updates sound like much... also, Maybe I didn't get you, but wouldn't an RSS feed accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @jondavidjohn - Alerts can come from a few different sources. One of them is from a submission form. Since the alert might go to a large number of people, it seems unreliable to have the user's browser sit there while the system sends out a lot of emails. I'd like it in a separate process "behind the scenes" but process/thread forking in PHP doesn't seem very reliable (and as I recall only works on *nix systems).

Comment: @fingerman - The alerts need to be sent in a timely manner once they are scheduled, no longer than 5 minutes I'd say.

Comment: @DWilliams - then just submit the form via AJAX to initiate the script so it doesn't lock up the browser.

Comment: If they are really the time-critical it seems not useful to me not to send them immediately. Crons are more useful for jobs, that "can wait" and that can benefit from a bigger set of data to process. It seems, that this cron usually will sent only a small amount of mails.

Answer (score 2):

Making the alerts asynchronous By separating the alert task from the rest of the code is desirable.

I don't see a problem with a cron script , I would ask why do you need to do it so often?
Setting a threshold is a good idea , but you would still need to check at the end of day or whenever to make sure it has fired anyway.

You could rather then use the whole overhead of controller (and rest of framework to get there) - maybe just make a lightweight CLI php script

Answer (score 1):

Ok, currently this is what you're doing

```
Timed Cron Job
 |
 |-check for any new updates (in database)
       |
       |-Send them

Some Event happens to trigger alert
 |
 |-Store alert to send later in database
```

Instead just do this

```
Some Event happens to trigger alert
 |
 |-Send it
```

Something is triggering your db insert

So instead of inserting, just call your email routine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: As he said in the above comment, his alerts come from various sources with only one being the submitted form.

Answer (score 0):

One simple workaround is to have your insertion script check if a threshold number of alerts has been queued since the last batch send. It wouldn't be a timed job, but it'd mean no more than the threshold # of messages is waiting at any time.

But if you do need it to be done regularly, and your site isn't busy enough to generate sufficient alerts to usually fall in under the time limit, then a cron job is your only practical alternative.